# Using Observables and Filtering an Array List in Angular App

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, filter

I am using observables in my Angular app, and it's working as expected. However, I am running into one situation that's a little confusing. In one component I am successfully subscribing to the observable, and then filtering the results, like this:

```
this.clientsService.getAll()
    .subscribe(resRecordsData => {
        this.records = resRecordsData;
        this.inactiveRecords = this.records.filter(record => record.category && record.category.includes('inactive'));
        this.records = this.inactiveRecords;
    },
    responseRecordsError => this.errorMsg = responseRecordsError);
```

However, in another component, while I am doing virtually the same thing, I am getting an error printed to the console that reads:

> EXCEPTION: _this.records.filter is not a function

This what that component looks like:

```
optionReceived(option) {
    console.log('Consulting: ' + option.toolbarLabel);
    if (option.toolbarLabel === 'OT') {
        console.log('Consulting: OT Filter Activated!');
        this.clientService.getByCategory('consulting', 1, this.pagesize)
        .subscribe(resRecordsData => {
            this.records = resRecordsData;
            this.OTRecords = this.records.filter(record => record.type && record.type.includes('OT'));
            this.records = this.OTRecords;
        },
        responseRecordsError => this.errorMsg = responseRecordsError);
    } else {
        return this.records;
}
```

What's the issue in the second case? Why am I getting the error there and not in the first case?

Comment: If you hover over this.records in each case, do you see the data types? Are they different in the two examples?

Comment: They look the same: (property) ConsultingComponent.records: any[]

Comment: "records" is set to an empty array in both components.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not filter before you subscribe

```
this.clientsService.getAll()
    .filter(record => record.category && record.category.includes('inactive'))
    .subscribe(
        resRecordsData => {
            this.records = resRecordsData;
        },
        err => this.errorMsg = err
    );
```

I believe Angular uses RxJS, take reference from http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-filter

Comment: Either way, though - the question is, why does the second example return an error when the first one doesn't? In both cases I am filtering after subscribing. So that alone is not the issue.

Comment: The filter will work for Array not if the result is single item. Are you sure you are getting a collection there? Can put a console.log

Comment: Very interesting. To my surprise this worked! Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

It is because of the async nature, you can use skipWhile operator to

```
this.clientService.getByCategory('consulting', 1, this.pagesize)
    .skipWhile(data => {
         if(data.length) {
             return false;
         }
     })
    .subscribe(resRecordsData => {
        this.records = resRecordsData;
        this.OTRecords = this.records.filter(record => record.type && record.type.includes('OT'));

    },
    ((responseRecordsError) => {this.errorMsg = responseRecordsError});
```

Note : Make sure that `this.records=[];` is instantiated

Update :
You should not assign `this.records=this.OTRecords;` inside the subscription because of which you got the undefined error.

In the first case filtered elements might contain more than one object(array) but not in the second case

Comment: Still getting the same error. Also, if async was the issue, then surely that would be an issue for both. My point here is that the second example returns an error, and the first one doesn't.